# Where should I migrate this question to?

Tags: support, specific-question

*[UltraEdit FTP not working with DreamHost](https://superuser.com/questions/350868/ultraedit-ftp-not-working-with-dreamhost)* is not really about a problem with UltraEdit, but about a configuration problem at an ISP.

What is an appropriate site to migrate this question to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At the base of it, it read like a question specific to webhosting. And in this narrow case, Dreamhost.

Both shoes of which appear to be fertile grounds on migrating the question in review to [the Webmasters sisterhood](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/21341/ultraedit-ftp-not-working-with-dreamhost).

If it's wrong, we'll soon see the question die a migratory death. And probably a flaming bag of Baby Ruths.